# I cannot use Oracle SQL Developer to connect to Oracle Expression Edition in Windows 10

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I recently installed Oracle Expression Edition on my Windows 10. I tried to use Oracle SQL Developer to connect to it. But I got this error:

```
***Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
  (CONNECTION_ID=d+A27hgtTOq/DlpPcoFxvA==)***
```

Here is the content of the tnsnames.ora file:

```
*XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )
LISTENER_XE =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost))(PORT = 1521))
ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )*
```

Here is the content of listener.ora file:

```
*DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = XE

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\Oracle\dbhomeXE)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\Oracle\dbhomeXE\bin\oraclr.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )*
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Your question doesn't include the connection information you have entered in SQL Developer. Are you sure the database service is running, as well as the listener service? Can you connect through other means, such as SQL\*Plus?

Comment: Did you mean Oracle Express edition (XE) https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/xe.html ?  Latest version?  Definitely need the information Alex asked for; please [edit] your question to add this information.  Have you tried `tnsping`  yet?

Comment: Both X E and listener services are running. I can use sqlplus to connect to it.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the XE is  last version.